# How do I programmatically import (in Access) a dBase table whose name will change it's last 3 letters as batches are made?

Tags: import, dbase

I am trying to programmatically import a dBase table whose last 3 letters of the name changes according to that day's batch number before posting eliminates that table. The user will key the 3 letter batch number on the form with the button to run the code. The table permanently exists as X:\mmm\dmodata\DMOAT___.dbf. Here is my code:

```
Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String

strPath = "X:\mmm\dmodata\" 
strFile = "DMOAT" & Me![ChooseBatchNum] & ".dbf"

strPathFile = strPath & strFile

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "dBase III", _
    strPathFile, acTable, strFile, "Imported", False
```

It works as far as accurately accepting the variable (dmoatAHC.dbf, for instance) except the error says "X:\mmm\dmodata\dmoatAHC.DBF is not a valid path" but it definitely is because manual import works great but that is unacceptable for the user. It is not ODBC. I have never had this problem before.

Comment: `X:\mmm\dmodata\dmoatAHC.DBF` is *not* a valid path. It's a fully qualified filename (path + filename), but it's not a *path* (which would be the drive and directory *without* the filename). `X:\mmm\dmodata\\` is a valid path, `X:\mmm\dmodata\dmoatAHC.DBF` is not. The error message is correct; you just have to carefully read the words to understand what it's telling you. :-) I'm suspecting you have `strPathFile` and `strfile` reversed in the `TransferDatabase` call, but I don't have Access installed on this machine to test.

Comment: Thanks Ken! You are exactly right. strPathFile and strFile are not reversed but strPathFile should not be in there at all - only strPath. Obviously, I am not a "real" programmer - just some VBA in Access. I miss my long time programmer colleague who always helped me with this sort of thing. This site has provided me with great tips from time to time and you all are great. I am glad I got the nerve to ask my question. Sometimes I just need a fresh eye!! - J